# D3js force layout update nodes and links

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

My objective - 
I am trying to give calculated [x,y] to nodes after node is dragged so that node occupies position based on what I calculated rather than where it was dropped.

Relevant examples - 
I have seen examples of updating nodes and links in forcelayout. Say for example,

https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1095795

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795

My approach ( which is not working ) -

In my case the requirement is slightly different from example above. After dragging a node ( I do a force.stop() to avoid force layout taking over position assignment for dragged node ), I reassign the node to a different [x,y] based on where the node is dropped.  Give it a d.fixed. After doing this I update my nodes. Node occupies the calculated [x.y] position and not where it was dropped. Till this step, all fine.

However on subsequent drags of other nodes (which is when drag.resume() kicks off automatically ), the node that was dragged in previous step occupies the [x,y] based on where it was dropped earlier and not based on my calculated [x,y] which it occupied nicely on drag end of previous step.

I thought force layout is not updated with nodes and links. So I updated force layout with new nodes and links as below,

force.nodes(newNodes)
      .links(newLinks)
      .start();

I do this in mouseup.drag

Still it is not working, any help appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You need to show us some code here.

Comment: Please find link to fiddle below. jsfiddle.net/lkanikka/Lymtedrq For the sake of simplicity, after a node is dragged and dropped, I am placing it in[10,10]. In practical example, it is different. 

Once the node is placed, after drag end, I drag another node. The node that I dragged earlier moves back to an [x.y] which is where it was dropped and not [10,10] ( the calculated [x,y] )... 

Looks like the [x,y] of where it is dropped is stored in the force layout. How to update the forcelayout with new [x,y] ? I have update the graph array in mouseup and did force.start(). It did not work...

Comment: You need to set `px` and `py` attributes as well https://jsfiddle.net/Lymtedrq/1/

Comment: Thank you ... it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the position, you need to set the `px` and `py` attributes, which are used by the layout internally, as well. Changed (and simplified) example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lymtedrq/1/).